# ECS images in a single task communication

Tags: docker, networking, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS task that runs two images in the same container. These two images try to communicate with each other. I am able to do this on my local by creating a network and running both on the same IP, and passing the IP as an ENV variable in the Dockerfile. It works perfectly fine with no issues.

However, when I push these images to ECS cluster running on awsvpc mode, I came across this answer and also this documentation where they say awsvpc runs on localhost interface. I tried replacing the IP addresses with 127.0.0.1 and it does not work unfortunately for unknown reasons.

Here are my two Dockerfiles being hosted on ECS:
Dockerfile 1

```
FROM cubejs/cubestore:v0.32.3
ENV CUBESTORE_WORKERS=127.0.0.1:10001
ENV CUBESTORE_META_PORT=9999
ENV CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1:9999
```

Dockerfile 2

```
FROM cubejs/cubestore:v0.32.3
ENV CUBESTORE_WORKERS=127.0.0.1:10001
ENV CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1:10001
ENV CUBESTORE_WORKER_PORT=10001
ENV CUBESTORE_META_ADDR=127.0.0.1:9999
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here? I see this error specific to the library I am using but it should still indicate that there is problem establishing communication with the given server name

```
ERROR [cubestore::cluster] <pid:1> Failed to get warmup partitions: Internal: Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:9999: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

Here is my task-definition file. Please note that all the sensitive info has been obv removed, so there is nothing wrong with the file:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "cubestore-router",
            "image": "",
            "cpu": 1,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 9999,
                    "hostPort": 9999,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_WORKERS",
                    "value": "127.0.0.1:10001"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME",
                    "value": "127.0.0.1:9999"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_META_PORT",
                    "value": "9999"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "cubestore-worker1",
            "image": "",
            "cpu": 1,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 10001,
                    "hostPort": 10001,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_WORKERS",
                    "value": "127.0.0.1:10001"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_META_ADDR",
                    "value": "127.0.0.1:9999"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_SERVER_NAME",
                    "value": "127.0.0.1:10001"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_LOG_LEVEL",
                    "value": "trace"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CUBESTORE_WORKER_PORT",
                    "value": "10001"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "taskRoleArn": "",
    "executionRoleArn": "",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 1,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.24"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "4096",
    "memory": "8192",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2023-03-16T19:43:23.318Z",
    "registeredBy": "",
    "tags": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have an ECS task that runs two images in the same container.

That statement makes no sense. Each container is created from exactly one image. What you mean to say is that you have two containers running in the same ECS task.

Looking at your task definition, the `cubestore-router` container is listening on port `9999` and the `cubestore-worker1` container is listening on port `10001`. The `cubestore-router` container should be able to access the `cubestore-worker1` container via `127.0.0.1:10001` and the `cubestore-worker1` container should be able to access the `cubestore-router` container at `127.0.0.1:9999`.

If that is not working, then I would suspect that the software you have running in the containers is simply not allowing requests from `127.0.0.1` for some reason, or perhaps one container is still starting up when the other container is trying to access it.

From an ECS/Fargate perspective the containers should absolutely be able to communicate with each other on their respective ports at `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Mark is right about his response, the containers can communicate but I would like to point out the exact error because this is not a software issue as suggested. What's happening here is that your router is not available when the worker tries to establish the connection. To fix it, you just need to modify the order of the container's startup order.

To your "cubestore-worker1" just add this:

```
    "dependsOn": [
        {
            "containerName": "cubestore-router",
            "condition": "START"
        }
    ]
```

This is true given that you are running your container on Fargate, for people using EC2 instances and a different network mode, the solution could be different.

Also, I am certain of this solution because I just fixed it while trying to implement CubeJS ;)